# Issues with LDAP PHP code - Cannot find user name against LDAP

Tags: php, html, active-directory, ldap

I've been trying to create a simple PHP LDAP login page that once successful would be implemented in my web application. I've never setup an LDAP authentication login before so this is all new to me. I've been looking at several PHP login form examples online but cant get any to work. I found an example page via https://www.hawaii.edu/bwiki/display/UHIAM/LDAP+Authentication and i'm using there code to test my LDAP test page. Below is the authentication code I have setup:

```
<?php

    // LDAP configuration
    $host          = 'ldap://ldap.server.name.example';
    $baseDn        = 'ou=people,dc=cgi,dc=ca';
    $username_attr = 'uid';
    $admDn         = '';
    $admPw         = '';

    // Global error message for LDAP authentication
    $ldap_status   = NULL;

    /*
     * Authenticated a username.  The reason for a failure can be
     * gotten from $ldap_status.
     *
     * Return boolean
     */
    function ldap_authenticate($username, $password) {
        global $admDn, $admPw, $ldap_status;

        error_log("authenticate($username)");
        if (!isset($username) || $username == '') {
            $ldap_status = "no username entered";
            return false;
        }

        if (!isset($password) || $password == '') {
            $ldap_status = "no password entered";
            return false;
        }

        $ldap = _get_ldap_conn();
        if (!isset($ldap)) {
            $ldap_status = "No connection to LDAP server";
            return false;
        }

        if (! _bind($ldap, $admDn, $admPw)) {
            $ldap_status = "Can't contact LDAP server";
            return false;
        }

        $dn = _lookup($ldap, $username);
        if (! isset($dn) || $dn == '') {
            return false;
        }

        if (_bind($ldap, $dn, $password)) {
            return true;
        }
        $ldap_status = "No such user or bad password";
        return false;
    }


    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //-----  Helpers
    //-----  Don't call these directly.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    // Return LDAP resource or NULL
    function _get_ldap_conn() {
        global $host, $ldap_status;

        $ldap = ldap_connect($host);

        if (isset($ldap)) {
            return $ldap;
        }
        error_log("_get_ldap_conn() can't connect to $host" , 0);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Return boolean
    function _bind($ldap, $dn, $pw) {
        $rc = false;

        /*
         * Caution: The caller must check for a blank password because
         *          binding with a blank password will succeed as
         *          as anonymous bind.  When binding with the user's
         *          DN and password to authenticate them this will yield
         *          a false positive.
         */

        if (!isset($dn) || $dn == '' || !isset($pw) || $pw == '') {
            $rc = ldap_bind($ldap);
            $bind_dn = 'anonymous';
        }
        else {
            $rc = ldap_bind($ldap, $dn, $pw);
            $bind_dn = $dn;
        }


        if ($rc) {
            error_log("_bind() bound as $bind_dn", 0);
        }
        else {
            error_log("_bind() can't bind as $bind_dn", 0);
        }

        return $rc;
    }


    // Return DN for username or NULL
    function _lookup($ldap, $username) {
        global $username_attr, $baseDn, $ldap_status;

        $filter = "$username_attr=$username";
        $results = ldap_search($ldap, $baseDn, $filter,
                               array('dn', 'cn', 'username'));
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);
        $count = $info['count'];
        error_log("_lookup() $count entries returned");

        ldap_free_result($results);

        if ($count < 1) {
            $ldap_status = "$username not found";
            return NULL;
        }
        if ($count == 1) {
            $dn = $info[0]['dn'];
            $cn = $info[0]['cn'][0];
            error_log("_lookup() found $dn ($cn) for $username");
            return $dn;
        }
        error_log("_lookup() found more than one entry for $username");
        $ldap_status = "Too many entries for $username";
        return NULL;
    }
?>
```

Now when attempting to lo login with all this setup I get a message saying:

```
ellison.montero is NOT Authenticated!
Reason: ellison.montero not found
```

I believe this is something to do with the following variables $username_attr, $admDn, and $admPw. I dont understand what these are or what its looking for. I had contacted my LDAP specialist and asked for the url and base dn. He gave me the following for base DN `ou=people,dc=cgi,dc=ca` and gave me the proper URL. So Im not sure what else I need at this point. Any help is apprecaited.

Comment: From reading a bit more on these function, I believe that I could not have enough permissions to perform the authentication setup I need. I Currently have regular user permission and I might need to request a service account. The other possibility is that I have possibly the wrong user name attribute. I will have to speak with my LDAP specialist tomorrow for some help on this. Please let me know if im on the right track here, I would appreciate any help.